# Is it okay to change the passwords in tomcat-users.xml for few roles?

Tags: tomcat

Is it okay to change the passwords in tomcat-users.xml for few roles?Will it create any problem?Is there any other dependent place i have to reset the password if i change in tomcat-users-xml file?

Answer (score 0):

tomcat-users.xml is a sample file that is not even active in standard deployments - thus there's no harm in any standard installation.

It contains the (clear text) credentials that you *might* use for accessing the administrative UI. As it's quite a bad idea to store credentials in clear text, this is not really a production environment.

Also note that the Realm-implementation that reads `tomcat-users.xml` is explicit in its non-production recommendation, in a way that you will need to restart tomcat whenever you want updated credentials to actually being used: The file is read once at startup and never again until the next startup of tomcat.

So: No harm, but there are a lot of better options to store those credentials. None as comfortable (and insecure) as `tomcat-users.xml` though